# Which predicate should i use if number of data exceed than 10 in core data swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i am storing data in core data. I want to remove data if its exceed count 10. I am not sure how to write predicate for this

for ex. if i have 20 record data from 11 to 20 should remove

my remove code is like

```
func removeOldData(_ removeAfterCount: Int) {
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "dataTrack")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        let predicaate =  ?? how to write predicate for this case

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicaate
        
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        
        do {
            try context.execute(deleteRequest)
            try context.save()
            print("Deleted Old Core data objects from Entity ")
        } catch let error {
            print("Detele Old data in error :", error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do they have a "date" property? How do you know that they need to be removed? because if you have 11 objects, and then need to remove 1, which one is it?

Comment: its just based on count..if data is more than 10.. 11th 12th....data should remove.. last inserted data will remove..yes i have data property

Comment: Then instead of Predicate which shouldn't be useful, you can simlply use the `offset` and set it to 10. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506770-fetchoffset

Comment: is there any example ..as this link just little info about offset

Comment: fetchrequest.offset = 10

Answer (score 0):

It depends on indexes you used in this class. It isn't always sorted by created time.
So if you use offset property of predicate, it could be correct or not.

- To flow offset approach, you should use created time property to sort it to ensure the correct result.
- But why you don't prevent from insertion?, you could avoid insert if number of record is exceeded 10. You could implement `func validateForInsert()` to avoid insertion.
- One more thing, in your source code, the `fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false` should be set to true, you don't need to fetch unFault of object to delete it.